# KendoUI Bar Chart - PlotArea Not Working As Assumed

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a Bar chart that is showing one single bar.  My intention is to have this as a sliver at the top of my page.  It is a breakdown of time spent by each partner in the process for the given page I am on.

The issue I am having is the PlotArea (my assumption, the entire rectangle of canvas to work on) which I have made green in the this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grandizer/ngxe5o5x/1/). The multi-colored bar is really all I want to see.  I am trying to remove the green completely.  So once it works, no matter what I set the following to:

```
'chartArea' : {
  'height' : 100,
  'margin' : 0
},
```

it makes the colored bar that height with no green area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the plotArea margin to -100

```
'plotArea': { 'margin': -100,background: "green" },
```

I agree that seems like strange behavior! This may need to change depending on the height of the chartArea.

Comment: Thanks (again) @JFlox.  I found that the `margin` was cutting off the smaller value on the right since it applies that value to all sides.  So I took it a step further and just dealt with the top and bottom margins. My final **solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Grandizer/ngxe5o5x/2/)**